# UDP client cannot talk through an external IP address

Tags: python, udp, client-server

I am running a UDP server and client (python). When within the same local network, the client is able to talk to the server. However when the server IP address is set to IP address of the router (which has UDP port forwarding to the server), the client is not able to talk with the server at all. I am wondering if anyone can point out why this works within the local network (on different machines) but I cannot make the client connect to the server using external IP address of the router to which both the client and server are connected.

The code for the client

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "<IP address of router which is port forwarded to server>", 5000
data = " Hello from Client" #.join(sys.argv[1:])

# SOCK_DGRAM is the socket type to use for UDP sockets
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# As you can see, there is no connect() call; UDP has no connections.
# Instead, data is directly sent to the recipient via sendto().
sock.sendto(data + "\n", (HOST, PORT))
received = sock.recv(1024)

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

Code for the server

```
import SocketServer

class MyUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):


    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print data
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    HOST, PORT = "<local IP address of server", 5000
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: firs, test your network connection via netcat or something like that: server -> nc -ul 5000; client -> nc -u server_ip 5000

Comment: You can only access your local server from outside if you configure the router to forward the outside port to the inside address of the server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding Other techniques are udp hole punching - for which the client and the server has to know each others ip&port. You can use pystun to get your outside ip address.

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured out what was going on.

Router is connected to two computers - Computer A and Computer B. Computer A can talk to Computer B using the local network (UDP server client). However when Computer A (UDP client) sends data to Computer B (UDP server) using the Router IP address (external IP address) with the router port forwarding to Computer B, it was not working. Apparently the server will only accept connections that originate outside the local network when the client uses the external IP address